# UITextField Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

I have 3 text fields. When user enters text into each text field, I want to use `UITextFieldDidEndNotification` to capture its text and assign it to a string.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldName:) name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification object:nil];

-(void)textFieldName:(UITextField*)sender
{
    if(sender==firstNameText)
    {
        firstName=textField1.text;
    }
    if(sender==middleNameText) 
    {
        middleName=textField2.text;
    }
    if(sender==lastNameText)
    {
        lastName=textField3.text;
    }    
}
```

But it's not passing into the `if` condition. How to do it?

Comment: Rather then this, Use textfield's delegate methods like **textfieledendediting**

Comment: The reason your code doesn't work is because the argument being passed to your `textFieldName:` method is an instance of `NSNotification`, not `UITextField`.

Comment: FYI - please look into the `if/else` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this or change as same in your code

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textFieldName:) name:UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification object:nil];// you need to pass your nil object here 

-(void)textFieldName:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UITextField *sender = [notification object]; // here you get your textfield
}
```

Comment: @Smartguy This is what I meant in my first comment below the question.

Comment: @rmaddy yes you are right but this  answer i resolved in Xcode now and then post this answer .

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved through UITextField's Delegate function.

You have to use UItextFieldDelegate method like

```
@interface YouClass : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Assign delegate to your textfield,

```
 _YourTextField.delegate = self;
```

Then you have to implement delegate function to receive end editing event of UITextField

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

     NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
     //You may perform your operation like

     if(textField ==firstNameText){
         firstName=textField1.text;
     }
     else if(textField ==middleNameText){
         middleName=textField2.text;
     }
     else if(textField ==lastNameText){
         lastName=textField3.text;
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Rather then using NotificationObserver, use the delegate methods.

Make sure you have set all textfield's delegate. And whenever you start to write following method can be called and operation can be performed.

By considering textfield1.tag = 0 , textfield2.tag = 1 and so on

```
- (BOOL)textField: (UITextField *) textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange) range      
    replacementString: (NSString *) string
{
  switch (textField.tag)
  {
    case 0:
      //Code for textField1
      break;
    case 1:
      //Code for textField2
      break;
    case 2:
      //Code for textField3
      break;
  }
}
```

Another methods you can try like **textFieldDidEndEditing**

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
   if (textField == textField1) {
      //Code for textField1
   } else if (textField == textField2) {
      //Code for textField2
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid `switch` statement. In Objective-C the value in the `switch` must be a integral type.